# Multi line chart for daily sales of every product using chart js

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, chart.js

so my problem i need to display a line chart of every sale of every product i'm using chartjs
so this is the query i used to get the data from the database

```
SELECT AVG(prix_gros) AS whole_price ,AVG(prix_detail) AS retail_price ,nom_produit ,TO_CHAR(created_at,'yyyy-mm-dd') AS date ,created_at FROM cr INNER JOIN cr_detail USING(id_cr) INNER JOIN  produit USING(id_produit) WHERE is_new=true GROUP BY nom_produit ,to_char( created_at,'yyyy-mm-dd'),created_at ORDER BY created_at";
```

and i have this response

```
[
  {
    whole_price: 16,
    retail_price: 32,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2022-11-25',
    created_at: 2022-11-25T13:32:59.435Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 17,
    retail_price: 34,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2022-11-25',
    created_at: 2022-11-25T13:32:59.435Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 14,
    retail_price: 28,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2022-11-25',
    created_at: 2022-11-25T13:32:59.435Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 17,
    retail_price: 33,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2022-11-27',
    created_at: 2022-11-27T19:36:46.508Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 18,
    retail_price: 35,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2022-11-27',
    created_at: 2022-11-27T19:36:46.508Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 19,
    retail_price: 40,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2022-11-27',
    created_at: 2022-11-27T19:36:46.508Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 22,
    retail_price: 33,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:12:44.584Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 18,
    retail_price: 40,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:12:44.584Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 29,
    retail_price: 52,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:12:44.584Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 22,
    retail_price: 33,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:13:36.245Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 18,
    retail_price: 40,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:13:36.245Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 29,
    retail_price: 52,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:13:36.245Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 22,
    retail_price: 33,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:16:19.057Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 18,
    retail_price: 40,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:16:19.057Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 29,
    retail_price: 52,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2022-12-03',
    created_at: 2022-12-03T13:16:19.057Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 66,
    retail_price: 99,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2022-12-27',
    created_at: 2022-12-27T04:25:44.765Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 55,
    retail_price: 55,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2022-12-27',
    created_at: 2022-12-27T04:25:44.765Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 35,
    retail_price: 39,
    nom_produit: 'produit 10',
    date: '2022-12-27',
    created_at: 2022-12-27T10:14:23.547Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 33,
    retail_price: 36,
    nom_produit: 'produit 11',
    date: '2022-12-27',
    created_at: 2022-12-27T10:14:23.547Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 39,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2022-12-28',
    created_at: 2022-12-28T13:49:36.343Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 39,
    nom_produit: 'produit 10',
    date: '2022-12-28',
    created_at: 2022-12-28T17:06:54.011Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 33,
    retail_price: 39,
    nom_produit: 'produit 05',
    date: '2022-12-28',
    created_at: 2022-12-28T18:23:59.549Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 33,
    retail_price: 66,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2022-12-28',
    created_at: 2022-12-28T18:26:25.806Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 23,
    retail_price: 36,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2022-12-29',
    created_at: 2022-12-29T11:13:17.151Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 280,
    retail_price: 290,
    nom_produit: 'produit 10',
    date: '2023-01-07',
    created_at: 2023-01-07T00:02:36.837Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 36,
    nom_produit: 'produit 04',
    date: '2023-01-07',
    created_at: 2023-01-07T19:17:15.517Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 250,
    retail_price: 260,
    nom_produit: 'produit 10',
    date: '2023-01-07',
    created_at: 2023-01-07T19:23:18.732Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 280,
    retail_price: 320,
    nom_produit: 'produit 04',
    date: '2023-01-07',
    created_at: 2023-01-07T20:38:55.636Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 45,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2023-01-09',
    created_at: 2023-01-09T10:08:28.997Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 39,
    retail_price: 48,
    nom_produit: 'produit 04',
    date: '2023-01-09',
    created_at: 2023-01-09T10:08:28.997Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 23,
    retail_price: 36,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2023-01-12',
    created_at: 2023-01-12T19:49:35.923Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 50,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2023-01-12',
    created_at: 2023-01-12T21:31:00.419Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 26,
    retail_price: 40,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2023-01-12',
    created_at: 2023-01-12T21:31:00.419Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 26.5,
    retail_price: 36.6,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2023-01-13',
    created_at: 2023-01-12T23:09:29.848Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 48,
    retail_price: 26,
    nom_produit: 'produit 06',
    date: '2023-01-13',
    created_at: 2023-01-12T23:09:29.848Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 20,
    retail_price: 50,
    nom_produit: 'produit 10',
    date: '2023-01-13',
    created_at: 2023-01-12T23:09:29.848Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 50,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2023-01-13',
    created_at: 2023-01-13T18:24:22.738Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 23,
    retail_price: 25,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2023-01-13',
    created_at: 2023-01-13T18:24:22.738Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 40,
    nom_produit: 'produit 01',
    date: '2023-01-16',
    created_at: 2023-01-16T16:12:26.055Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 23,
    retail_price: 36,
    nom_produit: 'produit 03',
    date: '2023-01-19',
    created_at: 2023-01-19T16:42:39.306Z
  },
  {
    whole_price: 36,
    retail_price: 39,
    nom_produit: 'produit 02',
    date: '2023-01-19',
    created_at: 2023-01-19T16:46:34.647Z
  }
]
```

my react component look like this

```
/* eslint-disable array-callback-return */
import React from "react";
import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "chartjs-adapter-moment";
Chart.register(...registerables);

const LineChartLayout = ({
  title,
  subtitle,
  dataSet,
  more,
  isChangingChartLine,
  fnLine,
}: any) => {
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    tension: 0.3,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "bottom" as const,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  let lineData: any[] = [];
  if (dataSet && dataSet.length !== 0) {
    for (let index = 0; index < more.length; index++) {
      let color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      const red = color;
      color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      const blue = color;
      color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      const green = color;
      lineData.push({
        label: more[index].nom_produit,
        data: [
          {
            x: dataSet[0].date,
            y: 0,
          },
        ],
        borderColor: `rgb(${red}, ${blue}, ${green})`,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)",
      });
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < dataSet.length; index++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < lineData.length; j++) {
        if (dataSet[index].nom_produit === lineData[j].label) {
          lineData[j].data.push({
            x: dataSet[index].date,
            y: !isChangingChartLine
              ? dataSet[index].whole_price
              : dataSet[index].retail_price,
          });
        } else {
          lineData[j].data.push({
            x: "",
            y: 0,
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const data = {
    datasets: lineData,
  };

  return (
    <div className="dashboard__stats-chart dashboard__stats-chart-line_card">
      <div className="dashboard__stats-chart-header p-m">
        <div>
          <h3 className="dashboard__stats-chart-title">{title}</h3>
          <h4 className="dashboard__stats-chart-subtitle mb-m">{subtitle}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="dashboard__stats-chart-header-btn">
          <p>GROS</p>
          <div className="toggle_btn mlr-s">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="chartLine"
              className="checkbox"
              checked={isChangingChartLine}
              onChange={fnLine}
            />
            <label htmlFor="chartLine" className="toggle"></label>
          </div>
          <p>DETAIL</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="dashboard__stats-chart-line">
        <Line options={options} data={data} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LineChartLayout;
```

and the result is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ0oR.png)

so a want my result to be labels are the products and the xAxis to be the dates from the oldes to the latest and the yAxis the prices

somthig like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj2sB.png)

and thank's for your help and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

so i found the solution
so line chart in chartjs needed a data structure like this

```
[
 {
  label: "product name",
  data: [
    { x: "2022-11-15", y: 30 },
    { x: "2022-11-15", y: 60 },
    { x: "2022-11-16", y: 80 },
    { x: "2022-11-17", y: 30 },
    { x: "2022-11-18", y: 40 },
    { x: "2022-11-19", y: 40 },
  ],
},
```

]

so created it using this

```
 if (dates && dataSet) {
//   lineData = [];
if (lineData.length === 0) {
  lineData.push({
    label: dataSet[0].nom_produit,
    data: [],
  });
}
dataSet.map((set: any) => {
  let found = lineData.find((el: any) => el.label === set.nom_produit);
  if (!found) {
    lineData.push({
      label: set.nom_produit,
      data: [],
      borderColor: `rgb(0, 0, 220, 0.9)`,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 220, 0.5)",
      tension: 0.4,
    });
  }
});
dataSet.map((set: any) => {
  lineData.map((line: any) => {
    if (set.nom_produit === line.label) {
      line.data.push({
        x: set.date,
        y: set.whole_price,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

}

hope that it help some one

if someone has a better solution it will cool to post it thank's